# Reversing an equaton based on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, resize, equation

So, don't tell any of my high school math teachers, but can't figure this one out.

I have an image set to resize based on whether the user is scrolling up or down. If they scroll down then I use:

```
    height -= height * 0.1
    width -= width * 0.1
```

And when the user scrolls up, it's set as:

```
    height += height * 0.1
    width += width * 0.1
```

Which is not making the image larger at the same rate the image was shrinking because it's based on 10% of the current size. I thought about saving the previous size, but if someone scrolls down, down, down, up, down, up, up, up, etc, it's not going to work. Anyone know the equation to use to have the image get bigger at the same rate it's getting smaller?

Comment: Store the original dimensions of the image on page load, and calculate the percentage change based on those figures, not the current size.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan The problem is that I need the rate at which the image shrinks/grows to slow down/speed up based on whether it's getting bigger or smaller, which is why I have it using 10% of the current size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have for shrinking is the same as:

```
height *= 0.9;
width *= 0.9;
```

and for enlarging:

```
height *= 1.1;
width *= 1.1;
```

The reason that one is not the reverse of the other is that `1 / 1.1` is not `0.9` but `0.9090909090909`. The reverse of increasing by 10% is not decreasing by 10%, but by about 9.1%.

If you use `1 / 1.1` instead of `0.9`, they will resize by the same rate. That is naturally the same as dividing by `1.1` to shrink:

```
height /= 1.1;
width /= 1.1;
```

Rory McCrossan has a point in calculating the size from the original size, that way you avoid accumulating rounding errors. Having a variable `zoom` that is an integer value, starting at zero for original size, and increasing by one for each 10% step, you get:

```
height = originalHeight * Math.pow(1.1, zoom);
width = originalWidth * Math.pow(1.1, zoom);
```

Comment: The zoom approach seems to work pretty well. With both, if you scroll up and down a lot the image gradually gets smaller and smaller. I think if I set a min/max size for the image, it should keep things from getting too weird. Thank you!

Comment: @Beaker: Strange, at zoom 0 you get `Math.pow(1.1, 0)` which is always exactly 1.0, so that should be the same as the original size. Have you checked that the stored original size remains the same?